# Linqpad performance vs Sql Management Studio

Tags: linq, entity-framework-5, linqpad

I have a Linq query I run in Linqpad against EF5, and it runs about 10 sec.  When I copy the generated SQL for that statement into SMS, it runs in less than 2 sec.

Obviously, EF adds more processing overhead than a direct SQL and LinqPad is running in my computer, not a server.  So I expect it to be a bit slower.

But is there some way I can trace the Linqpad and EF execution steps of the query so I can identify the bottleneck(s)?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you run the generated SQL from inside Linqpad?

Comment: Are you sure the LINQ you created is exactly the same as the query? It sounds like you could be querying in such a way as to miss an index when using the LINQ.

Comment: Hi @sgmoore, skeej didn't seem to respond, but I can recreate this and find that using the sql generated by linq to sql runs quickly but the linq itself runs slowly in linqpad. It doesn't hang per say just keeps saying executing. It is using a view, so I wonder if that is effecting it.

Comment: Interestingly removing the linq *where* statement made LinqPad return data. Which would make sense if the generate SQL was dramatically slowing it down, but the SQL ran fine either way.

Comment: Needs updating with the actual LINQ as I have a feeling I know what is happening but without the code I cannot be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [trial version of Ants Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) and move linqpad code to some test console application.

Your SQL query is faster than LINQ because LINQ query generation is a expensive procedure. To have a fair comparison, try to [compile the LINQ query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896297%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and compare a 2nd run with pure SQL. LINQ would still be slower (LINQ does much more a than just execute the query) but the difference should be way smaller.